# Postgres PERFORM COUNT(*) always returning 0

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I had a query in SQL for postgres to get the count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_variable FROM user WHERE something=something;
```

When I executed, it was returning the count. Then as per requirement this query was required inside a Postgres Function.When I used this query inside Function, Postgres replied

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>   HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function myfuntion(integer,integer) line 11 at SQL statement

I searched for this error and found that, this happens if query returned null while using `SELECT`, But already I was getting value when executed directly on command line.

And also some posts told to discard it we should use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`. So my new query inside the same function was

```
PERFORM COUNT(*) AS count_variable FROM user WHERE something=something;
```

After this function started working, but count_variable is always zero. I am checking it using raise after PERFORM query.

```
raise notice 'count_variable: %', count_variable;
```

count_variable is declared as

```
DECLARE
  count_variable int;
  ...
BEGIN
  count_variable := 0;
```

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong, or COUNT(*) function doesn't works inside function. If count(*) is not available, is their any alternative for counting rows. Somewhere I saw `@@ROWCOUNT` is also a variable to get row count, but it gives error.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you worked with MSSQL - stored procedures in PostgreSQL are significantly different - much more like Oracle - please, read documentation first - it is few pages https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: Thanks for info sir. Issue spotted as given in accepted answer with explanation. I was using `AS` instead of `INTO` as required for putting it into variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to discard the result of the select, so perform is the wrong choice. You want to store the result of the query in a variable, so you need an `INTO` clause:

```
DECLARE
  count_variable int;
  ...
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_variable 
  FROM "user" 
  WHERE something=something;
  ...
```

Just because you give the column an alias that is the same name as a variable, does not mean the result is stored in that variable. The column names have no relation with variables.

This is all explained in detail in the manual. Especially the chapter [Executing a Query with a Single-row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)